# How to import product into wordpress woocommerce from url and get command

Tags: wordpress, url, import, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I want to import products into word-press from URL.

I want to know the product table fully, I mean that I want to map my URL tables with woo commerce table. What are the products and attributes and prices and variables table in woo commerce?

For example

```
 INSERT INTO `catalog_product_website` (`product_id`, `website_id`) VALUES
```

Comment: You can accept my answer if it solved your problem by clicking the grey tick below the votes counter. Thank you = )

Answer (score 2):

The Wordpress Woocommerce stores products informations in `wp_post` (post_type = product) and in `wp_postmeta` (meta_key and meta_value for a post_id).

So, to store new products that way, you will have to do something like this :

**To add new product in the `wp_post` table** :

```
$post = array(
    'post_author' => $user_id,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => "publish",
    'post_title' => $product->part_num,
    'post_parent' => '',
    'post_type' => "product",
);

//Create post
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );
if($post_id){
    $attach_id = get_post_meta($product->parent_id, "_thumbnail_id", true);
    add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
}
```

**To set the category and the type of the new product** :

```
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'Races', 'product_cat' );
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'simple', 'product_type');
```

**And then set its values into `wp_postmeta` table** :

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'total_sales', '0');
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable', 'yes');
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_virtual', 'yes');
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', "1" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price', "1" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_purchase_note', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_featured', "no" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_weight', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_length', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_width', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_height', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', "");
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_attributes', array());
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', "1" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sold_individually', "" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_manage_stock', "no" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_backorders', "no" );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock', "" );
```

Hope it helps.

Source : [How to add product in woocommerce with php code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137501/how-to-add-product-in-woocommerce-with-php-code)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thank you.